# Gtkmm : DrawingArea :- Moving mouse over the drawing area crashes the GUI

Tags: c++, gtkmm

There is a drawing area at which we are showing live view of a camera connected.
Following are the 2 cases,

Case 1 : When we do not move mouse over the drawing area its working fine for hours without any crashes.

Case 2 : When we move mouse over drawing area, our GUI crashes within few seconds.

I am unable to understand what is the reason of crash.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Suggest you run it with gdb/other debuggers. As it stands you need to give us a loooooooot more info for us to diagnose this

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though I figured out where it does crashes but do not know what cause it to crash, Following are the piece of code where it does crash, m_drawingArea->m_imgParam.reInitParam();

Comment: My guess is you are not setting the m_drawingArea correctly, check the initialization code for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think mouse hover over the drawing area create a hidden slot which might disturb the sequence of data expose in drawing area. I have run in gdb also but unable to find any help.